# one combobox dependent on other combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this two combobox bound to 2 differnet database table. First is bound to table with 1 column with animal class (example Reptiles, Mammal, Amphibian etc) and the other has two colums Animal names and its respective animal class (example lizard - Reptiles, Snake - Reptiles, Dog - Mammal, Frog- Amphibian). Now what I want is when I select item in combobox1 the combobox2 should have the respective list of animal matching the item selected in combobox 1 with the respective animal class of each animal.

Here is what I have done till now

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3,1,3,1"
         Name="comboBox1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NameListData}, Path=Animal}"
         Selectionchanged="comboBox1_Selectionchanged" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Margin="3,1,3,1"
         Name="comboBox2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NameListData}, Path=Stream}" />
```

The selection_changed function

```
private static string aa;
 private void comboBox1_Selectionchanged(object sender, SelectionchangedEventArgs e)
 {
 aA = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
 }

 public static string aA
 {
 get { return aa; }
 set { aa = value; }
 }
```

The Collections to which 2 comboboxes are bound to and are located in MainViewModel class

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
public List<string> Animal
{
get
{
List<string> facult = new List<string>();

foreach (var a in dc.Faculties)
{ 

facult.Add(a.Animal1.ToString());
}

return facult;
}
}


string selection;

public List<string> Stream
{

get
{
selection = Schooling.Pages.NewStudentGeneral.aA;
List<string> stream = new List<string>();

var q = from c in dc.Streams where c.faculty ==selection select c;
foreach (var b in q )
{
stream.Add(b.stream1);
}

return stream;
}
}
```

Here the selection string is not getting the value selected in the combobox1 because whenever i hardcode and specify the selection part like in the statement down below

```
1 var q = from c in dc.Streams where c.faculty =="Reptiles" select c;
```

will give the respective animals for the Reptiles.

I guess if the selection variable was getting the selected value of combobox1 my problem have been solved. Or am am doing all wrong here?? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow tell your second ComboBox that it needs to update its items, you can either do this through implementations of `INotifyPropertyChanged`/`INotifyCollectionChanged` or do it manually. Since you have an explicit event for the selection change in the first ComboBox you might as well update the second manually as well, this could be probably done by changing the handler as follows:

```
 private void comboBox1_Selectionchanged(object sender, SelectionchangedEventArgs e)
 {
      aA = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      comboBox2.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
 }
```